# Проехать на машине: по двору или во дворе?

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно нужно говорить и писать:

*Проехать на машине по двору*

или

*Проехать на машине во дворе*?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **проехать на машине по двору.**

**Примеры:** Не дали проехать по двору. Проехать по двору нельзя, по въехать можно с другой стороны. Невозможно проехать во двор.

Приставка ПРО здесь имеет значение передвижения на какое-то расстояние, а предлог ПО обозначает направление этого движения **(по территории двора**).

Можно, конечно, сказать: я проехать во дворе еще 10 метров  и остановился, но такая ситуация встречается не часто.

Comment: ПО обозначает не направление, а поверхность, по которой едут. БТС: *1.Употр. при обозначении предмета, пространства и т.п., поверхность которого является местом, где происходит действие, движение кого-, чего-л., где располагается кто-, что-л.; вдоль чего-л., на поверхности чего-л. **Ехать по улице***

Comment: Я говорю об общем значении предлога ПО при управлении Д.п. - это обозначение направления действия.

Answer (score 0):

«*Проехать по двору*» значит пересечь один двор или его часть — **Проехать по нашему двору**.

«*Проехать во дворе*» значит совершить передвижение возможно и не в одном дворе (то же, что и *проехать дворами*, т. е. срезать путь) — **Проехать во дворе домов по ул. Строителей**.

Answer (score 0):

Контекст нужен.
***"Проехать по двору"*** - на вопрос *как?, через что?, каким путем?*
1. Побывать во всех/многих местах двора, объехать (весь) двор.
2. Сократить путь или объехать пробку путем проезда через проходной двор.

***"Проехать во дворе"*** - *где?*
Совершить небольшую поездку в пределах двора (например, с целью опробовать или продемонстрировать машину).

Это не очень строго, иногда значения пересекаются и взаимозаменяемы. В таких случаях вариант "проехать по двору" более употребителен.